# Call Web API from Access

Tags: ms-access, api-design

I need to call a Web API from an Access 2010 application. This is the first time I work with an API from within Access 2010, not sure how to do this. The API I need to call is this : https://currencylayer.com/

API gets the currency exchange between 2 or more currencies. My application will be used by company users in Europe and the USA, so I need the currency to be taken into account when a user generates reports. I tried several examples from the website, but they generate a JSON file which I am not sure how to read it as the format seems to change often.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MSXML library (installed by default on all recent computers).

eg:

```
Public Sub GetQuote2()

Dim objXML           As Object
Dim strSymbol        As String
Dim strURL           As String
Dim strWFormat       As String

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

strURL = "http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="
strWFormat = "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"

strSymbol = "MSFT"

objXML.Open "GET", strURL & strSymbol & strWFormat, False
objXML.Send

Debug.Print "Symbol = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(0)
Debug.Print "Trade  = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(1)
Debug.Print "Date   = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(2)

End Sub
```